# Laravel 5.2 File Upload always (/tmp) saved in DB

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I Have my code below, it successfully move the file in the desired path. My problem is that in db it always saved like (/tmp/phpI9zJ1F) with random characters after tmp/. How do I solve this problem?

```
$quiz = Quiz::findOrFail($id);
        $tmp = '';

        if( $request->hasFile('survey_image') )
        {
            $extension = $request->file('survey_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

            do{
                $rand = rand(11111,99999);
                $imageName = $rand.'.'.$extension;
                $tmp = $imageName;
                $is_duplicate = Quiz::where('survey_image', $imageName)->count();
            }
            while( $is_duplicate!=0 );

            $request['survey_image'] = (string)$tmp;
            $quiz->survey_image_path = 'images/surveys/';
        }

        $request->file('survey_image')->move(
                'images/surveys/' , $tmp);

        $quiz->update($request->all());
```

Comment: Which field on your `Quiz` model stores the image path? And what does your `$request->all()` contain? Hard to say without details of Quiz model and view/form code.

Comment: I have find solution, the FILE NAME (survey_image) in my view is similar to the db field which causes confusion to it. So I have renamed it and that solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use `replace()` or `merge()` in order to override the value in `$request`.

```
$request->replace(array('survey_image' => (string)$tmp));
```

Answer (score 1):

You hadn't explained much about it, but I believe that this is a method to only update a image.

So, I would do something like that:

```
    $quiz = Quiz::findOrFail($id);
    $tmp = '';

    if( $request->hasFile('survey_image') )
    {
        $extension = $request->file('survey_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        do{
            $rand = rand(11111,99999);
            $imageName = $rand.'.'.$extension;
            $tmp = $imageName;
            $is_duplicate = Quiz::where('survey_image', $imageName)->count();
        }
        while( $is_duplicate!=0 );

        $request['survey_image'] = (string)$tmp;
        $quiz->survey_image_path = 'images/surveys/';


        $request->file('survey_image')->move(
            $quiz->survey_image_path , $tmp);

        $quiz->update([
            'survey_image' => '/'.$quiz->survey_image_path.$imageName,
        ]);
    }
```

If you want to reuse your code, you can do something like: (Ps. Code not tested!)

```
/**
 * Handle File Upload
 * @param  UploadedFile    $file         [File from request]
 * @param  string          $path         [Path where to save the file]
 * @param  string|boolean  $current_file [An old file that you want to delete, before save the new one]
 * @return string
 */
public function updateImage(UploadedFile $file, $path, $current_file = false)
{
    //Set a random name to the file
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileName = str_random(32) . '.' . $extension;

    //Delete an old file first
    if ($current_file !== false)
        if (File::exists($current_file))
            File::delete($current_file);

    //Move new file to the directory
    $file->move($path, $fileName);

    return '/'.$path.$imageName;
}
```

And where you want to save on database:

```
if( !$request->hasFile('survey_image') ) return false; //Or what you want

$quiz = Quiz::findOrFail($id);

$quiz->update([
    'survey_image' => $this->updateImage(request('survey_image'), 'images/surveys/');
]);
```